# How Would I write this Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, powergrep

How would I write a Regular Expression for this?

```
Backup 1 of (anything here, maybe multiple words).html
```

I thought it would be this

```
Backup\s1\sof(.*)\.html
```

but it's not working. I'm using power grep... am I supposed to put something at the beginning and end? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
^Backup\s\d+\sof\s\([^\(\)]+\)\.html$
```

- `^` assert start of string

  - `Backup` matches characters "Backup"
  - `\s` matches any whitespace character
  - `\d+` matches one or more numbers
  - `\s` matches any whitespace character
  - `of` matches characters "of"
  - `\s` matches any whitespace character
  - `\(` matches character '('
  - `[^\(\)]+` matches one or more characters not including '(' or ')' characters
  - `\)` matches character ')'
  - `\.` matches character '.'
  - `html` matches characters "html"
- `$` assert end of string